# jQuery text() ignores leading blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, space

I'm working on a script, that should fill a table with some string data.
Using jQuery's append and text function works fine for data without a leading blank symbol.

But if the string starts with one or more blank symbols they are ignored.

Please have a look at this code example: https://jsfiddle.net/e56eb0zx/2/

```
var blank = " blank ";
var no_blank = "no_blank";

$("tbody").append(
  $("<tr>")
  .append($("<td>").text("|"+blank+"|"))
  .append($("<td>").text(blank))    // why isn't the blank displayed?
);

$("tbody").append(
  $("<tr>")
  .append($("<td>").text("|"+no_blank+"|"))
  .append($("<td>").text(no_blank))
);
```

How can i fix this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text), _Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space._

Comment: I am seeing both looking ok (I believe) in the fiddle in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not the problem. The generated markup contains the blank before and after the word blank. Its a problem with rendering the table.

Set the CSS-Attribute `white-space` to `pre` or `pre-wrap` for your table cells to get the desired behaviour.

See [this edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbr6tzvj/).